# How to use make to install an application on Cent-OS?

Tags: makefile, installation, centos5

I'm trying to install an application on Cent-OS from its source code. which is mpg123-0.59r the installation instruction is :

# make clean

# make

# make install

but each time I'm trying to excute make I get :

# You do not appear to have the kernel sources for your current kernel installed.

# make: *** [linux26] Error 1

I googled this issue and some links told me to install the the kernel-source and the kernel-devel !

I did but I'm still facing the same issue !

I'm using Cent-OS.5 with kernel version : 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5

Comment: Prove that you did.  They are source packages.

Comment: how could I prove that to you ?

Comment: Explain how you installed them.  By the way, usually you have to run `./configure` before running `make`, but I don't know how that is for this application.

Comment: executing this command : yum -y install kernel-source

Comment: and this command : yum install kernel-devel ......... 
this is the way that I installed both of them ............. I think yum should be smart enough to install dependencies..........  also this applications gives me the same issue its not about an application its about " make " .........   
# INSTALL ZAPTEL

# cd /usr/src/zap*

# perl -pi~ -e 's/# ztdummy/ztdummy/' Makefile

# make clean

# make

# make install

Comment: if you like to know more how I did added the kernel source : http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source this is the link I used.

Comment: Looks like you used the right way to install the kernel source ... maybe something relevant changed in the kernel sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution :

I was installing a driver-package and to use that you absolutely need the kernel source !

also, I was trying that on a public server so I don't know if its shared or not ! and I have no idea about the hardware type ! so after some research it appears that it was a shared server and it has an old hardware that not include much new implementations.

it ends up to change the server and everything goes fine.

Regards,